# How to show that a particular set is a subspace of a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

I need to show that c={0000,1100,1010,1001,0110,0101,0011,1111} is a subspace of v(4,2). In here do we need to add each element with another one in the set to show addition? I don't understand to do that. Can you please explain me? Then I need to show that {1001,0101,0011} is a basis for C by using elementary row operations. But when I add them to a matrix there is no need of elementary row operations. I can say that they are linearly independent. But I don't know that how to say that they span C. Can someone help me to answer this?

Comment: Your notation is obscure. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tiping tips.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But can't you give me an answer?

Comment: Precisely: I can't. "Obscure" means that the text fails to deliver effectively its content.

Answer (score 0):

C is all vectors with an even number of 1's. Adding two of those gives you again a vector with an even number of 1's: They have to disagree at even number of coordinates - otherwise their sum of 1's would be odd.

3 linearly independent vectors span a subspace with 8 elements, so they must form a basis.

Comment: I didn't understand the third sentence of 1st paragraph

Comment: An even number of coordinates must be different - otherwise the total sum of 1's for the two vectors would be odd.